# Condition with ending the slideshow

Tags: if-statement, powerpoint

By using VBA in powerpoint, how can I make a condition using “if” function to apply that if the user ends the slide show delete the animations or as:
If (the user ends the slideshow for a given slide)
Then
(Delete the animations…)

Comment: What have you tried so far?